# MySQL query optimization on WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, database, performance

is there any performance benefit in the way you arrange data in a `WHERE` clause on a MySQL query?
For instance, in this example the `categoryid` column is indexed

```
SELECT something 
FROM table 
WHERE date 
BETWEEN "date1" 
AND "date2" 
AND categoryid = "2"
```

VS

```
SELECT something 
FROM table 
WHERE categoryid = 2
AND date 
BETWEEN "date1" 
AND "date2"
```

Would there be any performance difference? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you care about performance, think about indexes.  For this query:

```
SELECT something 
FROM table 
WHERE categoryid = 2 AND
      date BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2  -- I'm assuming these are constants
```

You want an index on `(categoryid, date)`.  That is what you should do if you want performance.  MySQL will use this index regardless of the order of the conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

As for the queries without the index, it doesn't make a difference.  Any difference in the order of evaluations is likely to be swamped by the overhead of running a query anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your help! is there any limit for indexes on a single table?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "limit", but multiple indexes with multiple columns are supported.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, is it a good practice to have multiple indexes, lets say 5 indexed columns, in a table that has a total of 20 columns?

Comment: Each index add some overhead on inserts and updates, and also consumes disk space and RAM. So you should avoid creating useless indexes. However it's quite common to have many useful indexes per table.

Comment: thanks!, I guess performance > space and memory, in web application :)

Comment: Index limits: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#index_related -- You are unlikely to hit any of the limits.